# Wordpress Functionality Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to write a Wordpress functionality plugin but I am stuck in how to proceed. This is an HTML5 video plugin and I want to integrate it into any Wordpress post/page. This is what I did so far:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: plugin
Description: A Video gallery with thumbnails showing trailers
Version: 1.0
License: testing plugin
Author: Testing Users
Author URI: http://www.test.com
*/

$html = <<<HTML
  <script type="text/javascript" src="html5gallery==/html5gallery.js"></script>

 <div style="display:none;" class="html5gallery" data-skin="gallery" data-width="680" data-height="375">
 <!-- Add Vimeo video to Gallery -->
       <a href="link"><img src="link2" alt="name"></a>
       <a href="link"><img src="link2" alt="name"></a>
       <a href="link"><img src="link2" alt="name"></a>
       <a href="link"><img src="link2" alt="name"></a>
       <a href="link"><img src="link2" alt="name"></a>
       <a href="link"><img src="link2" alt="name"></a>
       <a href="link"><img src="link2" alt="name"></a>
       <a href="link"><img src="link2" alt="name"></a>

 </div>
HTML;

function video_gallery() {
    echo $html;
}

add_shortcode('wordpress_video_gallery', 'video_gallery');

?>
```

I installed the plugin but when I add the Shortcode on a page/post nothing is appearing.

Comment: What plugin you used? They build some `shortcodes`. You need to define that on your post or page.

Comment: Why is your HTML in the air (outside any function)? If you go to the docs (http://codex.wordpress.org), you'll find the solution. Please, note that we have a dedicated site to [wordpress.se]

Comment: @brasofilo I update my question - The issue I have is that when i call the shortcode nothing is showing up

Comment: Move the whole $html inside the function and do `return $html;`  instead of `echo`. PS: I've cleaned some of my previous comments

Comment: @brasofilo many thanks, how can integrate php code when using heredoc ?

Comment: Manual, always manual ;) http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: @brasofilo Once again many many thanks! - My last issue hopefully is that although I put the shortcode at the very end in my page after all content its simply putting it the first thing. How can I sort that ?

Comment: Read this comment again: `Move the whole $html...`

Comment: @brasofilo thanks!! - Is this the right way to do a sort of thing though ? Am I doing it right by creating a functionality plugin ?

Comment: Yes, it's perfect. See [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)

Answer (score 0):

Here some code for wordpress shortcode.

```
/*
Plugin Name: plugin
Description: A Video gallery with thumbnails showing trailers
Version: 1.0
License: testing plugin
Author: Testing Users
Author URI: http://www.test.com
*/

function video_gallery() {
// All your html and js code place here.
}

 add_shortcode('wordpress_video_gallery', 'video_gallery');

?>
```

Now if you add **[wordpress_video_gallery]** into your page or post you can view the output which you set into the **video_gallery** method in this page or post.